# Remove upstream from forked repository on GitHub

Tags: github

I forked a repository as a starting point for a new project, never intending to submit pull requests to the original repo. It's become annoying to have to select my own master branch every time I want to merge a branch in the GitHub interface.

How can I remove the reference to the upstream so that my own master branch will be automatically selected when creating merge requests?

I tried [editing `.git/config` as suggested here](https://gist.github.com/paulbooker/1650131), but my config file does not include any reference to the upstream.

Comment: Can you use git?

Comment: You mean to do the merges? I'm sure I could, though I'd prefer to remove the upstream as I'm afraid a fellow developer may someday accidentally send a pull request to the wrong place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be possible. However, for a small project like mine, I was able to go with the less-than-ideal solution without too much pain:

1. Make sure your local copy of the repo is up-to-date.
2. Take a screen shot of, or otherwise note, open issues currently in the repo.
3. Delete the repo on GitHub.
4. Create a new repo on GitHub with the same name.
5. In your local copy, modify the old remote to point to the new GitHub repo.
6. Re-add issues, collaborators, etc, as needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
git remote rm upstream
```

Just discovered this by plugging-n-chugging. This is the command that removes the specified upstream.

Make sure to verify that the old upstream has been removed:

```
git remote -v
```

Anything marked with "upstream" should have been removed.

Now you can simply add a new upstream and start over (an example for Github):

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/USERNAME/wellmap.github.io
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: Good tip! Unless I'm missing something, it looks like this removes the remote locally, but the upstream is still retained on GitHub.

Comment: @Nathan Arthur yes, you are right. GitHub retains the repo but your local git basically untracks and effectively deletes the upstream when you run the "rm" command -- from my best understandkmg